# Excel Continously Changing Cell Value Output

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to get values from one cell that continuously changes. The problem is that there is a formula on that one cell so when I write the VBA code to get the value, it doesn't show me anything.

Is there any way to get each value from a continuously changing/updating cell which includes a formula?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub all()

Dim p As Integer
Dim o As Integer

Dim Length As Single
Dim Width As Single
Dim Height As Single

Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info")
LastRow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row


o = 1

For p = 2 To LastRow
    Length = Cells(p, 2).Value
    Width = Cells(p, 3).Value
    Height = Cells(p, 4).Value

   Call boxes(Length, Width, Height)
   Call boxesLast3(Length, Width, Height)

   Total = Range("Q1").Value

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(o, 26).Value = Total
   o = o + 1

Next p

End Sub
```

Comment: WorkSheet_Calculate event?

Comment: What formulas and what VBA are you using? Can you provide an example to show what's happening?

Comment: please put them in the original post using [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37616456/edit)

Comment: So the formula that I am using in the actual cell is "=IF($O$1<$M$1, O1,M1)" and that value is continuously changing based on some other values and VBA code.